# How to format two equations on the same row but then carry on with one of the equations below?

Tags: equations, formatting

This is my code:

```
The Lagrangian \eqref{eq:14} differentiated according to \eqref{eq:15} gives the equation of motion in terms of linear acceleration $\ddot{x}$:
\begin{align} \label{eq:17}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right) =\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \Rightarrow \qquad \qquad \frac{d}{dt}(m\dot{x})=m(l+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-kx+mg\cos\theta \nonumber \\ 
m\ddot{x}=m(l+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-kx+mg\cos\theta \nonumber \\
\ddot{x} = (l+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-\frac{k}{m}x+g\cos\theta.
\end{align} 
The same process is done according to \eqref{eq:16} to generate the equation of motion with respect to $\ddot{\theta}$:
\begin{align} \label{eq:18}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right) =\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} \Rightarrow \qquad \qquad \frac{d}{dt}[m(l+x)^2\dot{\theta}] = -mg(l+x)\sin\theta \nonumber \\
m(l+x)^2\ddot{\theta}+2m(l+x)\dot{x}\dot{\theta} = -mg(l+x)\sin\theta \nonumber \\
(l+x)\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{x}\dot{\theta} = -g\sin\theta \nonumber \\
\ddot{\theta}=\frac{-g\sin\theta-2\dot{x}\dot{\theta}}{l+x}
\end{align}
```

which gives this output: [image]

I wish for the systems of equations on the right to be aligned (not necessarily with the other system, but within its own) and to not vertically overlap with the equation on the left (as the second system currently does). Would someone please show me how to do this? Apologies if unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! You already dialed the right environment for that, `align`, but are not really using it. To use it, you need to set alignment points with `&`. So to first approximation I'd like to suggest.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
The Lagrangian \eqref{eq:14} differentiated according to \eqref{eq:15} gives the equation of motion in terms of linear acceleration $\ddot{x}$:
\begin{align} \label{eq:17}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right)& =\frac{\partial
L}{\partial x} &\Rightarrow \qquad \qquad \frac{d}{dt}(m\dot{x})&=m(l+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-kx+mg\cos\theta \nonumber \\ 
&& m\ddot{x}&=m(l+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-kx+mg\cos\theta \nonumber \\
&& \ddot{x} &= (l+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-\frac{k}{m}x+g\cos\theta.
\end{align} 
The same process is done according to \eqref{eq:16} to generate the equation of motion with respect to $\ddot{\theta}$:
\begin{align} \label{eq:18}
\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right)&
=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} &\Rightarrow \qquad \qquad
\frac{d}{dt}[m(l+x)^2\dot{\theta}] &= -mg(l+x)\sin\theta \nonumber \\
&&m(l+x)^2\ddot{\theta}+2m(l+x)\dot{x}\dot{\theta}& = -mg(l+x)\sin\theta \nonumber \\
&& (l+x)\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{x}\dot{\theta} &= -g\sin\theta \nonumber \\
&& \ddot{\theta}&=\frac{-g\sin\theta-2\dot{x}\dot{\theta}}{l+x}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility, which also incorporates an upright differential `d`, which is common in physics, and an `\ell` that can be distinguished better from 1, is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm{d}}
\begin{document}
The Lagrangian \eqref{eq:14} differentiated according to \eqref{eq:15} gives the equation of motion in terms of linear acceleration $\ddot{x}$:
\begin{align} \label{eq:17}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}\right)& =\frac{\partial
L}{\partial x} \quad\Rightarrow &
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(m\dot{x})&=m(\ell+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-kx+mg\cos\theta \nonumber \\ 
&& m\ddot{x}&=m(\ell+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-kx+mg\cos\theta \nonumber \\
&& \ddot{x} &= (\ell+x)^2\dot{\theta}^2-\frac{k}{m}x+g\cos\theta.
\end{align} 
The same process is done according to \eqref{eq:16} to generate the equation of motion with respect to $\ddot{\theta}$:
\begin{align} \label{eq:18}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}}\right)&
=\frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} \quad\Rightarrow & 
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}[m(\ell+x)^2\dot{\theta}] &= -mg(\ell+x)\sin\theta \nonumber \\
&&m(\ell+x)^2\ddot{\theta}+2m(\ell+x)\dot{x}\dot{\theta}& = -mg(\ell+x)\sin\theta \nonumber \\
&& (\ell+x)\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{x}\dot{\theta} &= -g\sin\theta \nonumber \\
&& \ddot{\theta}&=\frac{-g\sin\theta-2\dot{x}\dot{\theta}}{\ell+x}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options: Aligning the systems by themselves, or aligning them across the text break (using `\intertext`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The Lagrangian~(14) differentiated according to~(15) gives the equation of motion in terms of linear acceleration~$\ddot{x}$:
\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \biggl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \biggr) 
    &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \Rightarrow 
    & \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (m \dot{x}) &= m(l + x)^2 \dot{\theta}^2 - kx + mg \cos\theta \nonumber \\
    & &                                m\ddot{x} &= m(l + x)^2 \dot{\theta}^2 - kx + mg \cos\theta \nonumber \\
    & &                                 \ddot{x} &= (l + x)^2 \dot{\theta}^2 - \frac{k}{m} x + g \cos\theta.
\end{align}
The same process is done according to~(16) to generate the equation of motion with respect to~$\ddot{\theta}$:%
\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \biggl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} \biggr) 
    &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} \Rightarrow 
    &    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} [m (l + x)^2 \dot{\theta}] &= -mg (l + x) \sin\theta \nonumber \\
    & & m(l + x)^2 \ddot{\theta} + 2m (l + x) \dot{x} \dot{\theta} &= -mg (l + x) \sin\theta \nonumber \\
    & &             (l + x) \ddot{\theta} + 2 \dot{x} \dot{\theta} &= -g \sin\theta \nonumber \\
    & &                                              \ddot{\theta} &= \frac{-g \sin\theta - 2\dot{x} \dot{\theta}}{l + x}
\end{align}

\noindent\hrulefill

The Lagrangian~(14) differentiated according to~(15) gives the equation of motion in terms of linear acceleration~$\ddot{x}$:
\begin{align}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \biggl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}} \biggr) 
    &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \Rightarrow 
    & \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} (m \dot{x}) &= m(l + x)^2 \dot{\theta}^2 - kx + mg \cos\theta \nonumber \\
    & &                                m\ddot{x} &= m(l + x)^2 \dot{\theta}^2 - kx + mg \cos\theta \nonumber \\
    & &                                 \ddot{x} &= (l + x)^2 \dot{\theta}^2 - \frac{k}{m} x + g \cos\theta. \\
\intertext{%
The same process is done according to~(16) to generate the equation of motion with respect to~$\ddot{\theta}$:%
}
  \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \biggl( \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\theta}} \biggr) 
    &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial \theta} \Rightarrow 
    &    \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} [m (l + x)^2 \dot{\theta}] &= -mg (l + x) \sin\theta \nonumber \\
    & & m(l + x)^2 \ddot{\theta} + 2m (l + x) \dot{x} \dot{\theta} &= -mg (l + x) \sin\theta \nonumber \\
    & &             (l + x) \ddot{\theta} + 2 \dot{x} \dot{\theta} &= -g \sin\theta \nonumber \\
    & &                                              \ddot{\theta} &= \frac{-g \sin\theta - 2\dot{x} \dot{\theta}}{l + x}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Since your document settings seem to provide for a wider text block, the equation number alignment should be better.

A suggestion: Introduce some space in your code so that it is more readable. It'll aid in debugging the content.